# How to remove 'submit query' from a form submit?

Tags: html

I have an html form and the submit button says "submit query". How can I remove this text? I am using a background image for the submit button and this text is messing up the button :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the text with jquery: $('#btnSubmit').val('');

Answer (score 56):

If you do not give your submit button a value

```
<input type="submit" />
```

instead of something like

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

it will display 'submit query' by default. Try giving it a space `&nbsp;` as the value.

Answer (score 10):

use:

```
<input type='submit' name='btnTest2' value=''>
```

Leave the value blank and there will be no words on the button. Since you're using a background image a for the button, give the button a height and width, otherwise it will display as a small gray blip (because there are no words on the button).

Answer (score 5):

Just use the value attribute as shown below:

```
 <input value="Whateveryouwant" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 4):

Background images are not content. If you want to use an image to tell people what a submit button will do, use a real image. As a bonus that allows you to provide alternative text for users who cannot see the image (e.g. because it failed to load or because they are blind).

```
<button type="submit">
    <img src="example.png" alt="Submit">
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to give it a value:

```
<input type='submit' name='btnTest'>
<input type='submit' name='btnTest2' value='Push Me'>
```

In the example above, `btnTest` renders as "Submit Query" while `btnTest2` renders as "Push Me".  Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** You can do this to not display any text.

```
<input type='submit' name='btnTest2' value='' style="width:100px;">
```

Comment: i do not want to display any value.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this was relevant then, but we would use type="image" rather than type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

Just put a space between the value quotes. Simple fix.

**Read** the question **before** you reply. You may actually help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not work, at least not in a CMS. I've tried the space and the  `&nbsp;` but IE8 will not recognize it. If I put the same in the value, it reverts back to 'Submit Query'. Just updating for anyone else who finds this method through a search.

**EDIT :** I added `text indent: -9999px;` to my CSS, and it seems that it worked. I still added the space in the value attribute for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.  If you don't set a value for a submit button it defaults to "Submit Query".  I assume you are using an image for your submit button since you have the default value.

If you want to fix it for IE8 add a text indent using CSS which will push the default value off the screen.

```
text-indent:9999px;
```

If you want to fix it for IE9 you also need to change the default value because the text-indent doesn't work :(  in your submit button add the following:

```
value=" "
```

I found this to work without a non-breaking space and tested it to my satisfaction on the IE's on browserstack.  If you want to use the breaking space, feel free; I'll include the code.

```
value=" &nbsp; "
```

Also, thank you to the other stack-responders, you helped me fix this issue on IE9.

Also you inspired me to post my findings here and possibly help others!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like a jQueryUI dialog button then you do not want to have the input button show up in the form, but rather just have it in the footer of the dialog. I accomplished this by doing the following:

Because IE will automatically put in an `<input type="submit" />` I put this in the form instead: `<input type="submit" style="display:none" />`

Then later in the dialog JavaScript I put:

```
$("#register-dialog").dialog({
   title: "Register",
   modal: true,
   width: 700,
   buttons: {
            Register: function () {
                $('#registrationForm').submit();
            },
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the text with jQuery?

jQuery:

```
$('#btnSubmit').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Plus the solutions mentioned with HTML and jQuery, you can put

```
font-size: 0px;
```

for the input and it wouldn't show the text anymore.

This worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

that's it browser show default use this  
  value="submit" is important

Answer (score -1):

use attribute `value="submit"`

Comment: i want to not display the submit

Answer (score -1):

nothing just do this

```
    <input type="submit /"
```

a slash with a space and u will not see the Submit or Submit Query no need to give value